Cauchy-Schwarz inequality - algebraic proof assuming euclidean inner product
Tried my hand at proving this while working through Schaum's LA book. Understood the proof from the book but wondered if mine was valid and looking for confirmation.
Assume $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n, | u \cdot v | \leq ||u|| ||v||$
I squared the RHS of the equation to get \begin{align*}
(||u|| ||v||)^2 = & \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 \sum_{j=1}^n v_j^2\\\\
= & \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n u_i^2 v_j^2\\\\
= & \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (u_i v_j)^2\\\\
= & \sum_{i,j=1}^n (u_i v_j)^2 + \sum_{i \neq j}^n (u_i v_j)^2\\\\
\end{align*}
The square of the LHS I noted as
$$
| u \cdot v |^2 = | \sum_{i=1}^n u_iv_i|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |u_iv_i|^2
$$
The first term I have for the RHS (last line) is equivalent to the inequality expression I have for the square of the LHS, specifically $\sum_{i,j=1}^n (u_i v_j)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n |u_iv_i|^2$. Since this inequality holds and the second term for the RHS is the sum of squared terms as well, this completes the proof.
I realise this may not be the more general case for all inner products but I started my proof this way and wanted to verify it. Thanks!

Inequality $|\sum_i u_iv_i|^2 \le \sum_i |u_iv_i|^2$ is incorrect. See for instance when $u_i=1=v_i$ for all $i$, the LHS is $n^2$ and the RHS is $n$.

@jlewk Thank you for correcting that. Do you have any suggestion on how to proceed with this?
